# Whence Rabbi Yosei Manda'ah?

Tags: names, amoroim, manuscripts, chulin-tractate

[Shmuel Safrai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shmuel_Safrai) in his book בימי הבית ובימי המשנה, p. 204, notes:

> "בכפר זה חי גם אמורא בשם רבי יוסי מנדאה"
> "In this village ([Kfar Mandi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kafr_Manda)) lived another amora by the name of Rabbi Yosei Manda'ah (= of Kfar Manda)."

in a footnote on this sentence he states:

> "בבלי חולין נא, א (לפי נוסחאות עיקריות)."
> "[Bavli Chullin 51a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Chullin.51a.5?lang=he&with=all) (according to the main versions)."

I've checked the Bavli manuscripts at the Genizah website and none of them have "רבי יוסי מנדאה". Most have "רבי יוסי מדאה", as do the printed editions. One MS has "בר מראה" and one has "ביראה". Does anyone know what Safrai was talking about?

Comment: +1 for efficient question title (and 'whence', shame I can't +2)